# How to access Form.Textbox.Text property when the source query returns no results?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am making a continuous form for searching that self-updates as the user types in multiple search boxes.

The code works up until the user types in parameters that don't correspond to any records.

The query then can't find anything and I get the error

> "Can't use the property or method when the control doesn't have the focus"

I could not figure out what element of the form is doing it. Adding the .SetFocus to the textbox control didn't help.

Any ideas on how to either

1. Set focus to the textbox again and prevent it from being lost, or
2. Figure out what is stealing the focus and disable it?

The following sub is called in the textbox_Change sub. I added a workaround.:

```vb
Private Sub RefreshTB(textbox As Control)
'This is to prevent Acces from removing trailing spaces
'If the textbox isn't empty and there is a space at the end, don't requery. This preserves trailing spaces as Access trims them on Me.requery
    If Len(textbox.Text) <> 0 And InStr(Len(textbox.Text), textbox.Text, " ", vbTextCompare) Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
'If the last character isn't a space, requery on change to show new results of the query
    Me.Requery
'The workaround: If the query returns no results, detect that, warn the user and clear search box. Requery to show some results again.
    If DCount("*", "DatasetsFilterQ") = 0 Then
        If MsgBox("No results found. The last TextBox you searched in will be cleared.", vbOKOnly, "No Records") = vbOK Then
            textbox = ""
            Me.Requery
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    textbox.SetFocus
    textbox.SelStart = Len(Nz(textbox.Text))
End Sub
```

I tried a filter but ran into the same error when passing .text value to the function.

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: Trap for null in textbox.Value

Comment: @Aldert 
First on ```textbox.SelStart = Len(textbox.Value)```
Then, if I ignore it, everywhere I use .Value or .Text, including in other textboxes that call this function.

Comment: @dbmitch The problem isn't null values in the textbox, but no results from the query. 
Or do you mean handle the query returning nothing in this function ? How would I do that ?

Comment: code to preserve and keep the trailing space is really costing you.  that then is forcing you to use .text of the text box (which only works when text box has focus).  First time I seen such a requirement, and it for sure is causing you big trouble and pain - all for a simple space. I don't have a solution, but for a continues form, this is even more difficult, since you only have one text box, and it is re-used for each row of data. So, now, depending on what row, existence of space will vary as the rows display and are filled out.  Do you really but really need that space in data?

Comment: It looks like this requeries your form every time user types a space in a textbox.  I don't understand why you are having to save its contents in tempstring and then restore it after the requery, i.e. I don't know why the value of textbox would disappear and need to be restored here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I actually figured out a cheaper way to do this (I simply don't requery when last character is space)

Comment: @deluxeinformation This is done so Access doesn't delete trailing spaces. I figured out a better way to preserve them (see above), but basically Access removes trailing spaces every time I used Me.requery, which made searching multiple words impossible.

Comment: Well if a user types in a search string, then spaces between words would be preserved. If I was to allow trailing spaces, then maybe have users type in "Forest Creek  " (in other words, surround with quotes - so above is search for Forest Creek and 2 trailing spaces.  So, I not sure if you spend the time trying to keep a space after a text box, or perhaps give the user some means to either use quotes, or maybe use "*" to mean extra spaces, and you do a replace right before the search. Maybe have to type Forest Creek** A bit more difficult UI. I OFTEN search code with a space, so good question

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `SelStart` to *Null*, so avoid that with *Nz*:

```
textbox.SelStart = Len(Nz(textbox.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks! This was useful, but not what the problem is about.